# I can't create global variables in a class Python

Tags: python, function, class, global-variables, nameerror

This is the code:

```py
class command:
    OutF = str()
    def Out(outputRange: int, ArgsFormat: list):
        global OutF
        ArgsFormat[0] = None;
        for i in range(outputRange):
            OutF += " " + ArgsFormat[i]

list = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "thisisjustexampleforwhathappend"]
command.Out(list.__len__(), list)
print(command.OutF)
```

And somehow when I'm trying to run the code it's saying:

```
NameError: name 'OutF' is not defined
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Make it an attribute: `self.OutF = ""`, then in your `for` loop: `self.OutF += ...`. Global variables are generally a bad idea anyways, and are rarely truly needed in good Python code.

Comment: Also, you're shadowing the built-in `list` by assigning it as a variable name. Don't do that.

Comment: `OutF` is not a global variable in this instance. It's a class attribute. `command.OutF += " " + ArgsFormat[i]` would work but this looks like it should just be a function rather than a class. There is no `self` parameter in `Out` so your class can never be properly instantiated, at least not in conjunction with using its `Out` method.